# Is the time complexity for this code segment O(n^2) or O(n^3)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the time complexity for the following two functions but I'm confused because inside one of the loops I'm calling a function. Do we consider it when calculating the time complexity. The function is called in the if statement condition check and it have a o(n). Also, I'm Sorting a list using a build in sorting function in java, Do I have to calculate it too?

```
public static List<Edge> getMSTUsingKruskalAlgorithm(int[][] graph, int[] singlePort) {

        List<Edge> edges = getEdges(graph);
        List<Edge> edges2 = getEdges(graph);
        DisjointSet disjointSet = new DisjointSet(graph.length);
        int chp=1000,x=-1,y=-1;
        List<Edge> mstEdges = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<singlePort.length;i++){
            chp=1000;
            x=-1;
            y=-1;
             for(Edge edge:edges){
                 if(( edge.x==singlePort[i]) && (!find(singlePort,edge.y))) {
                     if(edge.w<chp){
                         chp=edge.w;
                     x=edge.x;
                     y=edge.y;

                     }

                 }

             }

             int xSet = disjointSet.find(x);
             int ySet = disjointSet.find(y);

            if (xSet != ySet) {

                disjointSet.union(x,y);
                mstEdges.add(new Edge(x,y,chp));
                edges2.remove(new Edge(x,y,chp));
                for(Edge edge2:edges)
                {
                    if(edge2.x==x || edge2.y==x)
                        edges2.remove(edge2);
                }// end of loop

            }// end of if statement 

        }// end of loop 
        Collections.sort(edges2);

        for (Edge edge : edges2) {

            int xSet = disjointSet.find(edge.x);
            int ySet = disjointSet.find(edge.y);

            if (xSet != ySet) {

                disjointSet.union(edge.x, edge.y);
                mstEdges.add(edge);
            }
        }



         return mstEdges;


    }   



private static boolean find( int [] arr, int val)
    {
        boolean x= false;
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            if(arr[i]==val)
            { x=true;
             break;}

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: If you loop over a list in a method A, and decide to refactor the method to put the loop inside another private method B called by A, does that change the number of operations needed to achieve the task? Does the task suddenly become O(1), i.e executes in constant time, whatever the size of the list is?

Comment: You have to consider everything that happens inside the function. For example, you call `disjointSet.union` and `disjointSet.find`. The complexity of those operations has to be considered as well, but it's not clear from the code what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in singlePort

Your inner loop is `O(m)` where `m` is the number of edges in the edges list.
Within this loop you call the `find(singlePort)` function - treat it like a nested loop

the `find()` function is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the `arr` which is `singlePort`.

You have three levels of nested loops, thus you multiply their time complexities. NOTE: the exit condition is always a good indicator of the runtime

```
n * m * n = n^2 * m
```

If `m == n` then your algorithm is `O(n * n * n) = O(n^3)`

Otherwise, from the way it is written, the best we could say is:

```
O(n^2 * m)
```